# Need to sort a table in SPSS by numeric labels

Tags: sorting, spss

I have a few simple frequency tables in SPSS that have numbers as the value labels. I have the following table which currently looks like this:

[image: Frequency table]

And I'd like to sort this table in descending order:

> 100,75,50,25,0.

Sorting by `DVALUE` results in the order

> 75,50,25,100,0.

Comment: OAR must be a string. If you change it to a number (via `ALTER TYPE` or the `NUMERIC` compute function) it should by default be in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

The labels in a pivot table are always strings, so they will sort as you describe regardless of the variable type if you are sorting the pivot table itself.  However, if the variables are numeric, you can have the FREQUENCIES procedure sort them numerically, e.g.,
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=educ
  /FORMAT=DVALUE.
or the dialog  box equivalent.